# WebStorm - Live Template - Twig + Html not working

Tags: html, twig, webstorm, live-templates

I'm trying to add a simple snippet:

```
<a class="button button--link" href="{{ $1$.url }}" {% if $1$.target %} target="{{ $1$.target }}" rel="noreferrer noopener prerender" {% endif %}>
  {{ $1$.title|e }}
</a>
$END$
```

The result:

```
<a class="button button--link" href="{{ .url }}" target="{{ .target }}" rel="noreferrer noopener prerender" {%="${%$"  %}="$%}$" if="" .target="$_1_.target$" endif="">
  {{ .title|e }}
</a>
```

---

The problem is starting with `{% if $1$.target %}`, actually the `%` causing problems cause when I remove this `if` statement, all works.

Does anyone know how can I tell WebStorm that it should ignore this and not replace it to
`{%="${%$"  %}="$%}$" if="" .target="$_1_.target$"`

Comment: I suggest reporting this as a bug to [WebStorm Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB). My experiments show that it simply does not like ANY `{` symbols inside the HTML tag that are outside of the attributes values. Means: even if you remove `{% if ..%}` part and only leave `{% endif %}` .. or even something more simple .. it will still do this wrong stuff. It could be that some another plugin does extra job on the top but I cannot say what that might be.

Comment: The best I could do is this: `<a class="button button--link" href="{{ $VAR$.url }}" $IF$>
  {{ $VAR$.title|e }}
</a>
$END$` (NOTE: renamed `$1$` to `$VAR$` and introduced new `$IF$` variable. You now need to click on "Edit Variables" button and provide this `"{% if $VAR$.target %} target=\"{{ $VAR$.target }}\" rel=\"noreferrer noopener prerender\" {% endif %}"` in "Default value" column for `IF` variable and check "Skip if defined" for it as well. The downside is that it does not resolve `$VAR$` there (inside if section) and they need to be replaced manually.

Comment: That's all that I can think of about this issue right now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
Yeah, I will report this to WebStorm. Your workaround is good, but hopefully they can fix it.